# Best way to query the latest 1000 records from a table with thousands of rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have this postgresql code.

```
SELECT * 
FROM listings 
WHERE status != 'inactive' 
ORDER BY pkey DESC LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
```

Precisely, this will query the FIRST 1000 listings which is still active then sort it DESC.
Is there a best way to query the most recent/latest data?
Like for example I have a 500000 rows, now when I executed the query I want the 499000-500000 to be queried DESC.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: For that matter, why's it tagged php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to mince words, you said

> this will query the FIRST 1000 listings which is still active then sort it DESC

Which is not accurate. It will sort sort id DESC **and then** select the "first" 1000 (which, when sorted DESC can be thought of as the "last" 1000).

So, I think the answer to your question is *in* your question. The query you show will select the "last" (i.e. the records with the *greatest* values in column 'pkey`) 1000 records, ordered from the *most recent* to the one *a thousand ago*.

Note that the only real caveat is that it's not exactly 499000-500000, which would only be true if all 1,000 most-recent rows are "active".

Answer (score 0):

The last X records ordered by Y descending is the same as the first X records order by Y ascending, no?  You just then have to flip the order again once you have the results.

Simple example:

```
Data: C, E, B, A, D

Descending:  E, D, C, B, A
Descending (last 3):  C, B, A

Ascending:  A, B, C, D, E
Ascending (first 3):  A, B, C
Ascending (first 3, reverse sorted):  C, B, A
```